# Dump Twitter tweets from MongoDB to COSMOS

Tags: python, mongodb, hadoop, fiware, fiware-cosmos

I'm wondering what should be the best approach to dump a lot of tweets obtained from Twitter Streaming API into COSMOS in order to run a very simple MR job.

I was thinking on converting the collection documents to CSV, one per line probably, and then scp those to COSMOS. But I'm not sure if I need HIVE to run MR job once there or I can run the job in a more manual way. I was thinking on using Python for this, I prefer not having to use Java.

Thanks

Comment: Hi Alejandro:-)  I am not going to be helpfull here since I don't know much about COSMOS, but I though to drop a line just to say hello and ...
a) to ask, did you though about running your MR job in mongoDB it self ?
b) to tell you (probably u know this already) that exporting csv from mongo collection its very expensive time consuming operation. 
Regars - Nick

Comment: @nickmilon Thanks for pointing that out, I know that MR jobs can be run in MongoDB directly, I wanted to try COSMOS for that anyway. Regarding CSV, didn't really know, anyway this is going to be a batch process, so I really don't need real-time processing :)

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not necessary to dump the data, the [MongoDB connector for Haddop](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tools/hadoop/) could be used.  AFAIK, such a connector allows you to fetch the data only when it is going to be processed, getting *records* from the data *splits* as they are needed by the map processes at Hadoop. I mean, instead of using the default `FileInputFormat`, you use the `MongoInputFormat`, which implements the `InputFormat` interface and thus provides a method for getting a list of splits (which will be some kind of constant-sized partition of the data within MongoDB, e.g. a collection's chunck) and a method for getting records within the splits (e.g. a JSON document within a collection's chunck).

This kind of connector must be installed in all the nodes of the cluster; it is in our roadmap, together with a [connector](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-tidoop/tree/develop/tidoop-hadoop-ext) of our own that works in a similar way for CKAN. It is dued by the end of September.

Being said that, if for any reason you still want to dump the data to HDFS, your best bet is creating a script in charge of reading the MongoDB data and transforming it into NGSI-like notifications understable by [Cygnus](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-cygnus); then Cygnus will do the rest of the work.

Comment: does it need to be NGSI format yes or yes? CSV is not an option? I don't really see why I need Orion data format here...is it mandatory to use NGSI? Thanks

Comment: It has to NGSI just for the Cygnus input (it is the "language" Cygnus speaks), then the data will be stored in JSON format within the HDFS files.

Comment: Why do I need to use Cygnus here? I still don't see how this is connected with Orion-Cygnus...

Comment: Cygnus was suggested as a tool for moving the data from MongoDB to HDFS, in the sense Cygnus already implements the HDFS REST API part, thus you only had to implement a script in charge of reading the MongoDB data, building NGSI-like notifications and sending them to Cygnus. But that was just a suggestion. Such a script may be in charge of reading the data and dealing with the HDFS API itself, of course. Anyway, as said, we are working on installing the MongoDB connector for Hadoop, that should make unnecesary any script or Cygnus :)

Comment: good, let me know when that happens please, in the meantime, we just converted our collection to csv and sent it to Cosmos